# Space generated by "look alike" polynomials, $x^k$ with $k\in\mathbb Q_{+}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is related to another question I posted. I found this space in my applied work but I don't know if professional mathematicians have a name for it.

Consider the function $c:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ defined by $c(x)=x^k$ where $k$ is *rational* and greater than zero, $k\in\mathbb Q$ and $k>0$ and now define the set of functions: $$F=\left\{ f:\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R};\; f(x_1,\ldots x_n)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^K a_i\cdot c(L_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n))\right\}\quad\text{ with } L_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb R_{+} \,\text{affine}$$
(for the above to make sense we may need to restrict the domain so $L_i(\mathbf x)\ge0$).

Finally define $\mathcal F$ as the set of functions that can be expressed as linear combinations of finite products of functions in $F$. We have $f,g\in\mathcal F\Rightarrow f+g\in \mathcal F$ and $fg\in\mathcal F$. What algebraic structure is $\mathcal F$? Is it an ideal of some function space? If yes, which space? Also, does the space $F$ have any known name?

Comment: So there is no restriction on $c(x)$ for irrational $x$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: $c(x)=x^k$ where $k$ is a fixed, non-negative rational. An example would be, $c(x)=\sqrt{x}$. I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question, but there is no restrictions on the domain of $c(\cdot)$ besides $x$ is non-negative (since we are dealing with reals and not complex numbers).

Comment: Edit either $x_n$ by $x_m$ or $\mathbb{R}^m$ by $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Not for $f(x_1,....,x_n)$)

Comment: At first sight it seems to me an algebra over the reals. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks Ataulfo, I corrected the typo.